# How we can perform CRUD and Join operations using C/AL in NAV 2016?

Tags: dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

Currently I am working on NAV 2016. I came across some C/AL functions to Insert, Delete, Modify data from the table after retrieving them statically.

I want to know is there any use of SQL statement in C/AL to perform CRUD and join operations or we have to rely on C/AL inbuilt functions only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only c/al.

No join.

Fo read operations you can use Query object. It’s highly limited version of the SQL’s query. But it can do join.